# grid layout, last cell width

Tags: css

i'm really stumped by this current page i'm working on. The layout is a grid. 
The page is dynamic so the cells (divs) will be shifting about or even disappearing over time.

Because the location of the last cell will be changing, i want this last cell(div) to always extend horizontally across the remainder of the containing div. The point being to create a gray top border.

here's a link, it's obvious to see what i'm trying to do.
http://www.tomcarden.net/ug-post.html

i thought it would be easy. i thought the last cell (div) if not given a width attribute would naturally take up the remaining space in the row but it's not (?)

the class of this div is .last-cell.

i tried making the width:100% but that doesn't work. that breaks the page. the cell clears and starts a new row,  i tried clear:none so it would stay floated to left but that didn't work. this can't be that hard...?? can anyone lend some advice on this?,

big thanks in advance.

Comment: from your link, you want that last cell on the bottom row to be sitting where exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Quite tricky, but try adding this:

```
.last-cell {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -153px;
}
```

The `width: 100%;` will indeed make it into one row, bumped by the last picture, but with the negative margin you push it back up. To keep the image on top, apply:

```
.grid {
    z-index: 100;
}
```